# how to simulate page transition animations in a browser (similar to page swipe in mobile)?

Tags: html, animation, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I have a webpage that shows an image gallery for the current week, and I have a top bar navigation "prev" and "next" links to cycle through the galleries.  Currently clicking on the links causes a whole page refresh.  I think the user experience would be smoother if, when we click "next" we animate a slide-in of the next page content from right to left, and vice versa, if we click "prev" we animate the previous week of results from left to right (similar to how page transitions work in a mobile app when you swipe).  Note, I do not need to detect actual swipe gestures and I think jquery mobile markup is overkill.

To preload the data that will be sliding in I can make an ajax call, or even have the data preloaded in json for me to construct the replacement html off screen.  I will use html5 window history push state to change the url to the actual location we will be navigating to.  The only thing I haven't been able to find is to do the actual animation.  I have looked into carousels, but none of them quite do what I want.  Is there an existing library that handles just the animation of page transition, having that slight recoil bounce effect?

Thanks.

EDIT:  I just found jquery.animate which I think might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of jQUery based image gallery libraries that you might want to choose from.  If you can't find one to transition between different galleries teh way you want to, it should not be a problem to use jQuery to asynchronously load new galleries and then animate them into place.